# RegEx replace content within curly brakets

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm working on a small system with a WYSIWYG-editor that spits out HTML. In the generated code the HTML-links looks like this.

```
<a href="{link:3645}">One line</a><br/>
<p>yada yaya</p>
<a href="{link:2780}" target="_blank">Another link</a>
```

I would like to "scan" all the HTML and replace all the **Href Values** with a URL found in my database.

Something like this:
 - for each match of {link:x}
 - look in the database for id x
 - replace {link:x} with URL from database

I'm looking at `RegEX`, of course, but cant really figure out how to do this in the smartest way.

Any good ideas about links?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's the extraction part:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"<a href=""{link:3645}"">One line</a><br/>
<p>yada yaya</p>
<a href=""{link:2780}"" target=""_blank"">Another link</a>";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{([^}]*)\}");
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Version replacing links:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = @"<a href=""{link:3645}"">One line</a><br/>
<p>yada yaya</p>
<a href=""{link:2780}"" target=""_blank"">Another link</a>";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{link:([^}]*)\}");
        text = regex.Replace(text, ConvertLink);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    private static string ConvertLink(Match match)
    {        
        // Put real logic in here :)
        string link = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return "http://converted/" + link + ".html";
    }
}
```

Note that the regex here is slightly more specific - it forces the `link:` part. You may or may not want that.

I would say that using regular expressions in HTML isn't *often* a good idea - you should consider things like what would happen if the rest of the HTML itself contained curly braces. That's slightly less of a problem in the second form where we look for "link" but it's still not great...

Comment: I've heard that you should avoid RegEx on HTML, but is there another, better, way to solve this?

Comment: Would getting a bit better if you use a lookbehind assertion like this `new Regex(@"(?<=href=")\{([^}]*)\}")` to ensure that there is a "href=" before.

Comment: @stema: Any reason for doing it with a lookbehind rather than just putting it before the brace, not in a group at all? (Like the opening and closing braces are.)

Comment: @JonSkeet this is a zero length assertion, that means it will not be matched. You can ensure this part is before the stuff you want to replace, without replacing it also.

Comment: @stema: Ah, I see. Doh, yes. Of course an alternative is to include the href= in the replacement text :)

Answer (score 3):

I think is better to use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
it is allow you to parse html like LINQ to XML and you can find all href attributes and replace with value what  you need

and look at the example

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
  HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
  att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

where FixLink it is you function that set the correct value of href

or

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(txtLink.Text);

foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{ 
  HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
   att.Value = FixLink(att);
}
```

Comment: And i guess this is this is how to load a string into the doc insteed of a file: 
`HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(txtLink.Text);`

Comment: Yes you can load html or from string or from file

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is the to use the following regex in a loop till no further matches are found:

```
/href="\{link:(\d+)\}"/
```

When a match is found then `$1` should contain the link ID. Fetch the link from DB and replace it with the href.